# the task for the stream. put in Map

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to add up all the averages for each subject. As a result, I want to find out which subject is the easiest. I add up all the average values in physics , mathematics, History and as a result I will get a value of type String
//Ann Mathematics = 0.0 + Kate Mathematics = 1.66 + Bob Mathematics 2.33//3.99 //Ann History= 2.0 + Kate History= 2.33 + Bob History 3.66//7.99 //Ann Physics= 0.33 + Kate Physics= 1.0 + Bob Physics 2.66//3.99 I got the average for each student's subject, now I have to add them up, I don't understand how. Result:String lightestItem = ... // History

```
class Student3_1 {
private String name;
private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;

public Student3_1(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
    return marks;
}

public static Function<Map<String, List<Integer>>, Map<String, Double>> averageBySubject = marks -> 
    marks.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    entry -> entry.getKey(), 
    entry -> entry.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble()));


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
    markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(0, 0, 1));
    markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(0, 0, 0));
    markAnn.put("History", List.of(3, 3, 0));

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
    markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1, 2, 0));
    markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5, 0, 0));
    markKate.put("History", List.of(0, 2, 5));

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markBob = new HashMap<>();
    markBob.put("Physics", List.of(3, 2, 3));
    markBob.put("Mathematics", List.of(2, 2, 3));
    markBob.put("History", List.of(4, 4, 3));


    Student3_1[] students = {new Student3_1("Ann", markAnn),
    new Student3_1("Kate", markKate),
    new Student3_1("Bob", markBob)
    };
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averages = Arrays.stream(students)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student3_1::getName,
    student -> averageBySubject.apply(student.getMarks())));
    out.println(averages);


    Map<String, Double> map3 = averages.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
    students))
    String lightestItem = //history
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```java
        
Map<String, Double> subjectToAveragesSum = averages.values().stream().flatMap(value -> value.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.summingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: double key = 0;
        String sub = new String();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> s : subjectToAveragesSum.entrySet()) {
            if (key < s.getValue()) {
                key = s.getValue();
                sub = s.getKey();
            }
        }